# (Python) Socket Chat returning usernames as IP and Port

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, chat

I'm working on a TCP socket chat assignment for school. I'm having trouble getting the last part done, which is returning all usernames to the client when it asks for it. The client can write `/users` to get all connected users usernames, but instead gets the IP and PORT they are connected to, output example:
('127.0.0.1', 54612)

**Server Code:**

```
import socket, threading

clients = []
nicknames = []
BYTES = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"


def server():
    IP = "127.0.0.1"
    PORT = 9090
    BIND = (IP, PORT)

    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind(BIND)
        sock.listen()
        print("Welcome to Budget-Discord!")

        while True:
            client, addr = sock.accept()
            print("Connected with {}".format(str(addr)))       
            client.send('NICKNAME'.encode(FORMAT))
            nickname = client.recv(BYTES).decode()
            nicknames.append(nickname)
            clients.append(client)
            print("Nickname is {}".format(nickname))
            print(nicknames)
            #broadcast("{} joined!".format(nickname).encode(FORMAT))
            client.send("\t >>> Connected to server!".encode(FORMAT))
            threading.Thread(target=user_conn, args=[client, addr]).start()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error, socket: {e}")


def sendall(msg: str, conn: socket.socket): # Broadcast
    for client_conn in clients:
        if client_conn != conn:
            try:
                client_conn.send(msg.encode())

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error, sendall: {e}")
                byeee(client_conn)


def user_conn(conn: socket.socket, nicknames):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = conn.recv(BYTES).decode()
            if "/users" in msg:
                conn.sendall(bytearray(str(nicknames).encode()))
            if msg:
                print(msg)
                allchat = f"{msg}"
                sendall(allchat, conn)

            # else:
            #     pass

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error, user connection: {e}")
            byeee(conn)
            break


def byeee(conn: socket.socket):
    if conn in clients:
        conn.close()
        clients.remove(conn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server()
```

**Client Code:**

```
import socket, threading

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9090
BIND = (IP, PORT)
BYTES = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"

nickname = input("Choose your nickname: ")

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)     
client.connect(BIND)                            

def receive():
    while True:                                                
        try:
            msg = client.recv(BYTES).decode()
            if msg == 'NICKNAME':
                client.send(nickname.encode())
            # elif message == "/users"
            else:
                print(msg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error, client receive: {e}")
            client.close()
            break
def write():
    while True:                                                
        msg = f"{nickname}: {input('')}"
        client.send(msg.encode())

receive_t = threading.Thread(target=receive).start()            
write_t = threading.Thread(target=write).start()
```

I have tried different things, got tuple errors for the most part so I converted the /users in the server module to bytearray...

Answer (score 0):

In the function `server`, this line is sending `addr` as the second argument:

```
threading.Thread(target=user_conn, args=[client, addr]).start()
```

but the function `user_conn` has a second argument of `nicknames`:

```
def user_conn(conn: socket.socket, nicknames):
```

so send `nicknames` instead in `server`:

```
threading.Thread(target=user_conn, args=[client, nicknames]).start()
```

Comment: You are an angel, thank you so much my friend